# When importing database, it shows error

Tags: database, errors, import

I was importing my website' database on to another server but it is showing this error which I have no idea about:

[image]

I tried importing the database multiple times but failed.
I also checked 'Add Drop Table' field that comes when exporting the database file but it didn't do anything.

Comment: It is not unusual to see this collation this seems to be the best as WordPess is concerned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is as a result of your server not supporting the `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` collation type.

To resolve this you should convert the collation for all tables with `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` to `utf8_general_ci`

**If you're exporting through phpmyadmin, you can:**

1. Click the "Export" tab for the database
2. Click the "Custom" radio button
3. Go the section titled "Format-specific options" and change the
   dropdown for "Database system or older MySQL server to maximize
   output compatibility with:" from NONE to MYSQL40.
4. Scroll to the bottom and click "GO".

**OR run the following query on each of the affected tables:**

```
ALTER TABLE myTable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

**UPDATE:**
 You should also replace in your sql exported file `TYPE=MyISAM` with `ENGINE=MyISAM`

Comment: It is still showing an error

https://i.imgur.com/lYAYMiw.png

Comment: You should replace in your sql exported file `TYPE=MyISAM` with `ENGINE=MyISAM`

Comment: How do I replace it? Is this editable?

Comment: Yes it is. you can do a search and replace using any good text editor.

Comment: if so, dont forget to upvote his answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

For some, the collation `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` looks strange but WordPress uses this collation when possible. Other collations are the second best.

Note this line:

> // _unicode_520_ is a better collation, we should use that when it's available.

Some plugins will create `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` collation tables no matter what.

```
File: /var/www/html/test100.com/wp-includes/wp-db.php
761:    /**
762:     * Determines the best charset and collation to use given a charset and collation.
763:     *
764:     * For example, when able, utf8mb4 should be used instead of utf8.
765:     *
766:     * @since 4.6.0
767:     * @access public
768:     *
769:     * @param string $charset The character set to check.
770:     * @param string $collate The collation to check.
771:     * @return array The most appropriate character set and collation to use.
772:     */
773:    public function determine_charset( $charset, $collate ) {
774:        if ( ( $this->use_mysqli && ! ( $this->dbh instanceof mysqli ) ) || empty( $this->dbh ) ) {
775:            return compact( 'charset', 'collate' );
776:        }
777: 
778:        if ( 'utf8' === $charset && $this->has_cap( 'utf8mb4' ) ) {
779:            $charset = 'utf8mb4';
780:        }
781: 
782:        if ( 'utf8mb4' === $charset && ! $this->has_cap( 'utf8mb4' ) ) {
783:            $charset = 'utf8';
784:            $collate = str_replace( 'utf8mb4_', 'utf8_', $collate );
785:        }
786: 
787:        if ( 'utf8mb4' === $charset ) {
788:            // _general_ is outdated, so we can upgrade it to _unicode_, instead.
789:            if ( ! $collate || 'utf8_general_ci' === $collate ) {
790:                $collate = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
791:            } else {
792:                $collate = str_replace( 'utf8_', 'utf8mb4_', $collate );
793:            }
794:        }
795: 
796:        // _unicode_520_ is a better collation, we should use that when it's available.
797:        if ( $this->has_cap( 'utf8mb4_520' ) && 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' === $collate ) {
798:            $collate = 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci';
799:        }
800: 
801:        return compact( 'charset', 'collate' );
802:    }
```

> The `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` (Unicode Collation Algorithm 5.2.0, October 2010) collation is an improvement over `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` (UCA 4.0.0, November 2003).

There is no word on when MySQL will support later UCAs.

**The very latest UCA is 9.0.0 http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/**, but MySQL doesn't support that.